# Не ловится событие мыши на inkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf

**Задача** - нарисовать линию по выбору соответствующей кнопки на панели инструментов. 
 В своём коде я пробую реализовать следующий **алгоритм**: кликаем LMB на рабочую область, переносим курсор в другое место, удерживая LMB нажатой, отпускаем LMB - рисуется линия по координатам места, где кнопка была нажата и где отпущена. 
**Объявляю глобальные переменные:**

```
Point EndPosition;
Point StartPosition;
```

**Код:**

```
private void inkCanvas1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    {

        FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        StartPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(fe);
    }

private void Line_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        linePressed = true;
    }

private void inkCanvas1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        EndPosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(fe);
        if (linePressed)
        {
            this.inkCanvas1.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.Ink;
            Line l = new System.Windows.Shapes.Line();
            l.X1 = StartPosition.X;
            l.X2 = EndPosition.X;
            l.Y1 = StartPosition.Y;
            l.Y2 = EndPosition.Y;
            l.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            l.StrokeThickness = 5;
            inkCanvas1.Children.Add(l);
        }
    }
```

**В результате** линии рисуются следующим образом:
[image: Результат]

Как можно это исправить?

**P.S** Пробовал выводить координаты `EndPosition` в момент рисования в консоли, но безуспешно.

Comment: А что есть ваш `fe`?

Comment: @VladD: `FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;`, что интересно, событие `MouseDown` никогда не срабатывает. Если бы автор пользовался бы отладчиком, он бы это сразу увидел

Comment: @Андрей: Не, ну это я вижу, мне интересно, какой там реально объект лежит. Но если MouseDown не приходит, то тогда понятно, в чём проблема.

Comment: @Андрей там inkCanvas.
Заменял `e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(fe);` на `e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(inkCanvas1);` - результат тот же

Comment: Ну я понял как исправить, но как-то очень это костыльно.

Comment: @Андрей можно ознакомиться с вашим "костылём" =) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите в `InkCanvas` свойство `EditingMode="None"` и не меняйте его в коде. В режиме `EditingMode="Ink"` элемент не отслеживает событие `MouseDown`

Comment: Тогда возникает закономерный вопрос, а нафига вообще InkCanvas?

Comment: @VladD, я хз зачем он автору, там ведь в режиме `Ink` вообще след пера рисуется, что автор хочет сделать - непонятно и линию нарисовать и след от курсора тоже? Или он там хакерит - цвет линии пера выставил равным цвету фона, на скрине-то не видно следов от курсора...

Comment: @Андрей исправил, упустил момент, что нужно режим поменять, спасибо

Comment: @Андрей: Рисуется-то он сам, вопрос в том, а как потом нарисованное считать?

Comment: @VladD, из свойства `Strokes`? Вообще, конечно, раз у нас InkCanvas, то и рисовать надо с помощью `Stroke`, а не линиями...

Comment: @Андрей: Интересно, что Stroke не является `DependencyObject`'ом. Странно, почему? Это значит, что их не получится использовать с MVVM.

Comment: @VladD, `Strokes` - это свойство зависимости, надо привязываться к нему, а на слое VM работать уже со `StrokeCollection` (там есть `INCC` и `INPC`), сами `Stroke` наследуются напрямую от `object` и тоже реализуют `INPC`

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, в этом случае придётся в VM включать зависимости от PresentationCore.dll. Как-то не комильфо.

Comment: @VladD, это да, но куда деваться, если очень уж хочется использовать InkCanvas? Обвешать его АттачедПропертями?

Comment: @Андрей: Это вопрос не ко мне. Я не очень-то понимаю преимущество `InkCanvas`. Ну оно умеет подписаться на StylusDown и StylusUp, и запомнить точки движения. Вручную пишется за 10 минут.

Comment: @VladD, ну если вопрос к автору, то автор прекрасно и без MVVM обходится (пока)... :)